# Retrieve 'id' from an URL using regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I need to extract only the 'id' from an URL. The url format is given below. Currently, I use parse_url and substr function, which works. However, it is not a good choice if the length of 'id' changes, where regex comes into play. I am not well-conversant with regex, so I need an idea how to do it in other way e.g. regex.

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/stock-footage/53833534/portrait-lifestyle-leisure-caucasian-parents-children-snow-v.html'; 
$URLParts = parse_url($url);
// echo $URLParts['path'];  
$substring = substr($URLParts['path'],15,8);
echo $substring;
```

Comment: What is your issue with `parse_url()`.... `it is not a good choice if the length of 'id' changes` What on earth do you mean by this? The length of the id is totally irrelevant to the workings of parse_url().... looking at your code, it's not parse_url() that's your problem, but substr()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
preg_match("/.+\/([0-9]+).+/", $url, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

[live example](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/dgK)

Comment: I have selected your solution as my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can use this :

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.example.com/stock-footage/53833534/portrait-lifestyle-leisure-caucasian-parents-children-snow-v.html'; 
$URLParts = parse_url($url);

$exploded = explode('/',$URLParts['path']);

echo $exploded[2]; 

?>
```

Comment: I have voted you up. I am using your solution anyway, though my first preference was to use regex.